# Cakephp Email after several seconds/minutes

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there anyway in cakephp to send email within specified time?

I have a file upload website build using cakephp, which after finish uploading it will send an email for download link, then it will call up a php CLI to zip the file. During zipping, the site is closed already, so I have no idea when the zip process will finish. I was wondering if I can specified in cakephp email, to send the email after 1 minute for example, before the page being refreshed.

This is some code to show what happened

```
var xhr_zip;
xhr_zip = new XMLHttpRequest();
fd_zip = new FormData();
fd_zip.append("total_files", total_files);
xhr_zip.open("POST", "datas/zip/", true);
xhr_zip.send(fd_zip);

xhr_update_usage = new XMLHttpRequest();
fd_update_usage = new FormData();
xhr_update_usage.open("POST", "datas/update_usage/", true);
xhr_update_usage.send(fd_update_usage);

xhr_email = new XMLHttpRequest();

fd_email = new FormData();

xhr_email.open("POST", "datas/send_link/" + recipient + '/' + subject, true);
xhr_email.send(fd_email);

    xhr_email.onload = function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").removeClass("loading");
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            alert("Total Files : " + total_files + " Sent \n Total Upload Size : " + (total_upload_size/1048576).toFixed(2) + " MB");                   
            document.location.reload(true);
        }, 2000);
    };
```

so, after the zip triggered, even though it's not finish zipping, the script will move on to send the email and refresh the browser.

Comment: why not send the email after zipping

Comment: @Dagon because the zipping is done through php, while emailing through CakePHP. it's like 2 different applications. So, if I have to do it after zipping, I need to move the code into standard PHP code, which I'm trying not to do

Comment: cake is a framework, not another language.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are handling the zip progress already and can identify when the process is complete, so I would do the following:

I would recommend you create a new table and model named something like EmailQueue. Then I would create a shell, for example /app/Console/Command/EmailShell.php

```
/**
 * Shell to run background emails
 *
 * @property $EmailQueue
 */
class EmailShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array(
        'EmailQueue',
        'Model' // Name of model you are creating the zip for
    );

    public function main() {
        $this->out('You have hit the Email Shell.');
    }

    public function run_email_queue() {
        $emailQueueItem = $this->EmailQueue->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'EmailQueue.status' => 0
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'EmailQueue.created ASC'
            )
        ));

        if(empty($emailQueueItem)) {
            $this->out('Email queue is empty.');
            return;
        }

        // Assuming you have a field for file status which is updated on zip completed
        // Alternatively, you could use a separate shell or cli to check
        switch($emailQueueItem['EmailQueue']['file_status']) {
            case "complete":
            case 1:
                $status = $this->send_email($emailQueueItem);
                break;

            default:
                $status = false;
                break;
        }

        if($status !== false) {
            // Update the status so that the email isn't sent later on
            $this->EmailQueue->id = $emailQueueItem['EmailQueue']['id'];
            $this->EmailQueue->save(array(
                'status' => 1
            ));
            $this->out(' ### Sending Email Successful');
        }
    }

    public function send_email($emailQueueItem = array()) {
        // Your model which does the zipping should have the email logic
        // I would have it return true or false.
        return $this->Model->originalEmailFunction($emailQueueItem['EmailQueue']['model_id']);
    }

}
```

The above is a very simplified example of a shell, just put some sort of completed flag in your model or update the "EmailQueue" table once your shell has finished zipping then when your cron hits this shell it will send the email providing said flag is present - you may need a second shell to update the flag of the zip files if you can't handle it in your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to stay on the original page while the file uploads? If so, could you do you initial Ajax call with  a callback, and execute your email sending code in that callback?

Alternativaly, rather than sending the email straight away could you effectively queue it (maybe just by creating a record in a 'emails' table in the DB) and have a cron job check for emails that are ready to send, by looking to see if the uploaded file has finished being zipped?

Answer (score 0):

for the reasons of slick response time I would use an off-the-shelf queueing solution, for example:

```
https://github.com/MSeven/cakephp_queue#readme
```